# Can't get the right results using the orWhere query in Yii2 framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using the following code in Yii2 framework to get all the results (cars in my case) from mySQL database that contains specific tags:

```
$query->orWhere(['and',
            ['car_extra.field_id' => $this->carField->id],
            ['like', 'car_extra.value', $searchValue]
        ]);
```

For example there are 2 cars in the database.

Car **Ford** contains the tags: **abs**, **dvd-player**

Car **Jeep** contains the tag: **Parktronic**

When i search for the tag **"abs"** the search displays the **Ford** car which is ok, but when i search for both **"abs"** and **"Parktronic"** at the frontend search form, the search returns zero results because it search in the database for a single car that contain both of the tags **"abs"**  **and** **"Parktronic"**. How can i modify my code above so i can get as result both cars: Ford and Jeep ?

Comment: how can we be sure that it is the same case that you are describing ? can you show us the actual RAW query that you have created and have tested ? along with the output of the query that have using the above query builder, i assume that you are using the search model

Comment: You have not car with   both "abs" AND "Parktronic"  ..  so your query should be  "abs" OR "Parktronic" ... you could also try IN ( "abs", "Parktronic" )

Answer (score 1):

I have been using yii2 for 5 months but query building is really tough job. But here is the solution you can use this.

```
$query->andWhere(['car_extra.field_id' => $this->carField->id]);

$searchValue=explode(' ',$searchValue);
foreach($searchValue as $searchParam)
{
    $query->orWhere(['like', 'car_extra.value', $searchParam]); 
}
```

I have broken your search parameter into array and using it as single search value.
If you your search query is not separated with space then you can use explode(',',$searchValue) anything.

Comment: Query like that will actually find all records where field_id matches OR value contains one of the tag. That's because `orWhere` method basically does "(existing conditions) OR (new condition)". So with only one tag you will get something like `(car_extra.field_id = :p0) OR (car_extra.value LIKE :p1)`. So instead of finding cars that have at least one required tag and field_id match you will find all cars where field_id match and cars where field_id doesn't match but have required tags.

Answer (score 1):

You culd use a IN clause based on ana array for the searched  values

```
  $myArray = ["abs","Parktronic"]
  $query->where(['in','car_extra.value', $myArray]);
```

Comment: Note: `$query->where(['car_extra.value' => $myArray])` will result in `IN` expression if `$myArray` is an array. That can be used to simplify whole query to `$query->where(['car_extra.field_id' => $this->carField->id, 'car_extra.value' => $searchValue])` if the `$searchValue` is pre-processed to be a string with single tag or array of strings with multiple tags.